# Hausdorff spaces with asymmetric image relation

Tags: gn.general-topology

For any topological space $(X,\tau)$ we define $$R_{im}(X,\tau) := \{(x,y)\in X^2: (\exists f:X\to X) \text{ continuous and surjective with } f(x) = y\}.$$
Clearly, $R_{im}(X,\tau)$ is reflexive, and transitivity follows from the fact that the composition of two continuous surjective maps is continuous and surjective.

Is there a Hausdorff space $(X,\tau)$ such that $R_{im}(X,\tau)$ is not symmetric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many such spaces.

For example $\omega_1+1= [0,\omega_1]$ with 
the order topology.    A continuous map $f$ with $f(\omega_1)=0$ must be eventually constant, hence can have only countably many values.

But there is a continuous surjective selfmap $g$ mapping $0$ to $\omega_1$.

Comment: Or more simply, just take $\omega+1$.